# Cake PHP Pagination changes to limit records per page

Tags: cakephp, paginator

I have the following code in my calls/index.ctp. At the moment it is showing all records in one page. I want to limit 20 records per page. When I baked the project, the pagination was provided, but I'm still a beginner and doesn't know how to change the pagination. Can someone please help?

calls/index.ctp:

```
<div class="callsIndex">
    <h2><?php echo __('Call Details'); ?>   </h2>
    <div class="bottomButtonnew"><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Add Calls'), array('action' => 'add')); ?></div>


    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>

            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Call Date'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Call Time'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Comments'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Next Call Date'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Customer Name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Company Name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Employee Name'); ?></th>
            <th class="actions"><?php echo __(''); ?></th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($calls as $call): ?>
            <tr>

                <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($call['Call']['call_date'])); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['call_time']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['comments']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($call['Call']['next_call_date'])); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Customers']['customer_name'], array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'view', $call['Customers']['id'])); ?>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Companies']['company_name'], array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'view', $call['Companies']['id'])); ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Employees']['employee_name'], array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'view', $call['Employees']['id'])); ?>
                </td>
                <td class="actions">


                    <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $call['Call']['id'])); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <p>
        <?php
        echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
            'format' => __('Page {:page} of {:pages}, showing {:current} records out of {:count} total')
        ));
        ?>  </p>
    <div class="paging">
        <?php
        echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
        echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
        echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
        ?>
    </div>
    <br>

</div>
```

callsController:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class CallsController extends AppController {

public $components = array('Paginator');
public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 10
    );

public function index() {
        $userid=$this->Session->read('User.userid');
        if(isset($userid)&&$userid!=null)
        {
            $this->Call->recursive = 0;
            $this->set('calls', $this->Paginator->paginate());
            $result=$this->Call->getcalls($userid);
            $this->set('result', $result);
        }
        else{
            $this->set('loggedout',"loggedout");
            $this->render("../Pages/home");
            $this->layout = '../Pages/home';
        }


    }
//some code
}
```

Comment: Where is your find logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it easily by using pagination component.You should do it in your AppController.In your AppController you can type below code

```
Public $components =array('paginator');

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
       parent::beforeFilter();
       $this->Paginator->settings=array(
              'limit'=>10
       );
    }
```

Than in you index method just change this line

```
$this->set('calls', $this->Paginator->paginate());
```

I think that will work fine now.This code will work for all controller.But if you want to change this only your CallsController. Do this code.

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class CallsController extends AppController {
public $components = array('Paginator');

public function index() {

      $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'limit' => 10
    );
        $userid=$this->Session->read('User.userid');
        if(isset($userid)&&$userid!=null)
        {
            $this->Call->recursive = 0;
            $this->set('calls', $this->Paginator->paginate());
            $result=$this->Call->getcalls($userid);
            $this->set('result', $result);
        }
        else{
            $this->set('loggedout',"loggedout");
            $this->render("../Pages/home");
            $this->layout = '../Pages/home';
        }


    }
//some code
}
```

Note : There is two way to apply pagination one is by using component another is in controller.

Answer (score 1):

The correct call in your example should be like this:

$this->set('calls', $this->paginate());

So your code is:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class CallsController extends AppController {

public $components = array('Paginator');
public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 10 //Here can you change the default limit
    );

public function index() {
        $userid=$this->Session->read('User.userid');
        if(isset($userid)&&$userid!=null)
        {
            $this->Call->recursive = 0;
            $this->set('calls', $this->paginate());
            $result=$this->Call->getcalls($userid);
            $this->set('result', $result);
        }
        else{
            $this->set('loggedout',"loggedout");
            $this->render("../Pages/home");
            $this->layout = '../Pages/home';
        }


    }
//some code
}
```

Comment: i changed my code to the above, but still it displays all records for calls and does not limit to 10 records. @lamasgergo

Comment: Paginated records are in $calls variable. Advice1: Write out sql debug in your view file and check the mysql queries, is there any limit ?! i think you overwrite your $calls variable somewhere. Advice2: simple var_dump($this->paginate()); (or debug) in your controller to check what is the results of this function.

Comment: This is wrong !! you have mixed component pagination and controller paginate !!

Comment: Not wrong but will be deprecated in cake 3.0. You can use pagination without load paginator component in cake 2.x but recommened to use pagintor component directly. reference: lib/Cake.php @line 1068

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class CallsController extends AppController {

public $components = array('Paginator');
public $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 20
);

}
```

Comment: I added that code in my callsController but there is no change, still showing mall records. I have updated the question with my callsController index function. Is there anything that I need to change in that? @Sony

Comment: @sony this is not right, because you have used component in here, why you have use $paginate.Don't mixed component pagination and controller paginate!!